# Why do I get this error when opening Tor Browser

Tags: 20.04, ssl, tor-browser

I'm fairly new with Ubuntu and Linux in general. Out of curiosity I installed the Tor Browser, but when opening it, there is just this error message.

Thank you in advance!

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0xmb.png)

Comment: How did you install Tor?

Comment: I installed it first via Ubuntu Software. Then I reinstalled via sudo apt

Comment: I would uninstall it and then download and install from TOR homepage: `https://www.torproject.org/download/`.

Comment: This is one of the few cases, where you do not want to install software the ubuntu way, but instead do waht @Serafim suggested.

Comment: I downloaded it, got a tar.xz File. What to do next, sorry, still a big beginner

Comment: I'll make this an answer.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would never use Tor from an installation repository. The very reason to use Tor is anonymity. Uninstall and then:

1. Download from `https://www.torproject.org/download/`. You get a file with a name
   ending `tar.xz`.
2. Right-click on the file to unpack it (see to it that you have `xz-utils` installed)
3. In the directory that is the result of unpacking the `tar.xz` file you have a
   directory called `Browser` and a file called `Tor Browser Setup`. Double-click on
   the setup file and Tor will be properly setup and will start. The `Tor Browser Setup`
   file will change name to `Tor Browser`, which is the file you double-click in the
   future to start Tor.

You can place the directory where ever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

According to Serafim's post, very helpful, but if the file is not set up to be run as a program, you'll still get around the errors.

So for this, simply right click and select properties, and roll over to the permissions tab, then you'll notice the Program option at the buttom, mark this option, then you can move on to unpack the file.